# How to convert UTC time to local time from Mongo database itself?

Tags: java, mongodb, datetime, utc

I have a huge MongoDB database. Within that, I have an order collection. Where I store each order in UTC time. I am showing that orders in a graphical view. So the working is,

1. User select a particular date range
2. Convert that to UTC date range to local time date range and get all the orders of that date range
3. Iterate through all those documents in Java code (To convert UTC timestamp to the user's  local time based on the offset value that we get through API call)

So this step 3 is the concern. If the User selects past 3 months orders. The for loop in step 3 might have to iterate a million times as I have a million orders over that period of time. Is there any better way to do this? Can MongoDB functions help me with this?

Comment: Exactly what data type is your order date field in your database?

Comment: Can you inject the offset into a mongo db function? If yes, then MongoDB functions may possibly help you. If not, you can use `java.time.ZoneOffset` and `java.time.OffsetDateTime` in order to convert a UTC timestamp to various offsets.